# how to implement alt+tab like feature using java?

Tags: java, javafx, jna

Image shows what `getDisplayMedia()` does

[image]

I want to show user, all the current opened applications/windows (like that of alt+tab) using java. In javaScript we can do this by Media Devices interface `getDisplayMedia()`. I want to implement similar feature using java.
Is there any way to do this using JNA, or something else.

Comment: Check out the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433994/java-window-image/4682351#4682351 Apparently the window cannot be minimized for the example code to work properly, but you could work around that. Regardless, it will still screenshot all focused and unfocused windows.

Answer (score 2):

The method I'm sharing does the trick of pulling up the alt+tab menu using Java Robot and letting it close after a delay (It switches the window as well). Hope this helps!

```
public static void alt_tab() {
    Robot robot;

    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(5000);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I tried this, but is not reliable as if the user does not click on one of the windows he might get the wrong output. i want to hold the screen as long as user does not click on one of the windows given.

Comment: You would need to replace the delay with an MouseListener in your code for that function.

Comment: Use below link to resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549526/alttab-using-java-robot

Comment: Thanks Jdevr and Akash for your help... I will try this both methods.